# How to find a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I find and prove a basis for the subspace

$$\{(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4})\in \mathbb{F}^{4} : x_{1}+3x_{2}-x4=x_{3}+x_{4}=0\}$$

What I  tried was to reduce the amount of variables,

for example, since we have that $x_{3}=x_{4}$ we could write $x_{4}=-x_{3}$
so we could have $$(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},-x_{3})$$

Or $(-3x_{2}-x_{3},x_{2},x_{3},-x_{3})$ but then I wouldn't know how to represent it as row vectors

So can anyone help to explain to me how to do it?

Comment: Then take it apart with addition; you get $(-3x_2,x_2,0,0) + (-x_3,0,x_3,-x_3)$. Then if you let $x_2 = s, x_3 = t$ and factor out the $s$ and $t$ you can get anything in the vectorspace as a linear combination of those two vectors.

Comment: Notice that the subspace is described as the set of solutions of a homogeneous linear equation system. Solving this system gives you generators of the vector space. Then test if this generating set is already linear independent, and, if necessary, remove unneeded vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix of the system of equations is already in row-reduced form:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&3&0&-1\\
0&0&1&1
\end{pmatrix}$$
The main unknowns are $x_1$ and $x_3$, and the solutions are
$$\begin{cases}x_1=-3x_2+x_4\\x_3=-x_4\end{cases}\iff\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-3x_2+x_4\\x_2\\-x_4\\x_4\end{pmatrix}=x_2\begin{pmatrix}-3\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+x_4\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$